# Multi language in IOS APN (push notification)

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, apn

I am working on a booking app. And I would like to send a notification to user when there the booking status is update.

So I write some json in server side like this:

```
{
  "aps":
  {
    "alert": "update status",
    "category" : "booking approve", //can be "booking cancel" , "booking reject"
  }
}
```

And in the IOS side

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [NSObject : AnyObject]) {
  let aps = userInfo["aps"] as! [String: AnyObject]

  // need to customize and create notification message here

}
```

The problem is , how can I customized the message (according to the user language) after receive the status tag (e.g. booking approve) from the push notification?

Thanks for helping.

Comment: need to customize notification  alert ?

Comment: yes is it possible? e.g. receive "booking ok" , then notifiy "thanks for booking Mr. ABC, you are welcome to use our service etc....", thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look at the [Remote Notification Payload guide](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37109405/multi-language-in-ios-apn-push-notification) which lists all the key available for the notifications. The one you are looking for is **loc-key** :

> **loc-key** : A key to an alert-message string in a Localizable.strings file for the current localization (which is set by the user’s language preference). The key string can be formatted with %@ and %n$@ specifiers to take the variables specified in the loc-args array. See Localized Formatted Strings for more information.

Instead of sending a string in a arbitrary chosen language, send this key and the alert will show a translated text, according to the localisations available for your app.

Also, since iOS 8.2, **title-loc-key** is available for the title displayed in Apple watch when receiving a notification.

Comment: thanks for advice , one problem is how to get the language of the user device, can I just detect the language once the device receive the message , and override the notification message?

Comment: You don't have to detect the device language, the system takes care of it by itself. It's like using localizable.strings, the system knows which localization to use.

Comment: sorry I afraid I am confused , is that means the server do not need to know every device language? To simplify , I would like to only show "you have receive message" in notification , but multi lang. which field / file are need?

Comment: The server does not need to know every device language : just send a String key to your device (ex : "KEY_BOOKING_APPROVE"). In the localizable.strings file in your device, add the translation for the key for each language (I assume you already use this file for the multi language). 
Thus, if later you add a new localization for your iOS app, you don't have to modify the server, since the translation of the message is included in the iOS app.

Comment: Don't hesitate to ask for further help if you need it.